# Spring tool suite - Eclipse - Code format does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, format

I am using STS ( Spring Tool Suite ) - Version 3.9.5 ( Eclipse 4.8.0)

I imported Google Java Code Style

[image]

A part of Google Java Code Style is working like: replace tab to space ( 2 spaces)

But when I hit format code ( Source --> Format ) it is still using default Eclipse code format.

Example this case:

[image]

Nothing changes at all when i try to format the code.

I setup maven **fmt-maven-plugin**. So I need to run `mvn fmt:format` to correct my code 
[image]

I think the code should be correct when I hit Source --> Format.

Do I miss some options somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

To format code you can try these :

1. Select all code : Clt + A
2. Format : Clt + Shift + F

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

just take the plugin (google-java-format-eclipse-plugin_1.6.0)

and paste into folder in C:..\springtoolsuit-4.11.0.RELEASE\dropins

and close and open springtoolsuit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhpe6.png)